# What is deep-rl?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for [deep-rl](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rl) but it has no wiki and I'm not really sure what it is. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Deep reinforcement learning, I assume? The approach that beats people in Go, etc.

Comment: The tag was created here: [Why does Q-Learning use epsilon-greedy during testing?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/270618/) That supports @amoeba's guess. Another issue is what to do about the tag.

Comment: "Deep RL" is a standard term in the deep RL community, so I'm pretty sure that's what it is. I can write an excerpt, but we can also replace all 9 instances with [deep-learning] + [reinforcement-learning]. @gung

Comment: @amoeba Thanks for doing the legwork! But there is a touch of tautology to the statement "'Deep RL' is a standard term in the deep RL community." ;-)

Comment: Tautology of touch!

Comment: (Zero hits on google? Seriously? It should be a book title or something.)

Comment: This includes stuff like deep Q networks, actor critic models, hybrid CNN-RL methods, but maybe not  things like multi-armed bandits or monte carlo methods.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make [deep-rl](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rl) a synonym of [reinforcement-learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinforcement-learning). If users want to emphasize that their network is "deep," they have the option to add [deep-learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning).

Comment: Do you want it made a synonym of `[deep-learning]` as well?

Comment: @gung If it all, I'd say it should rather be a synonym of [reinforcement-learning]...

Comment: @amoeba, in 9/11, the Q already has r-l, but only 4/11 have d-l. My impression is that people start w/ the general category (ie, r-l) & then want to augment that by noting that this is the 'deep' version. That's the reasoning behind my suggestion. That said, I'm fine w/ it if people prefer the other mapping.

Comment: I'm not convinced that we need [tag:deep-learning] at all since it amounts to branding, but I'm apparently in the minority. I agree with amoeba: my view is that [tag:reinforcement-learning] is the more specific designation. Additionally, OP can specify that the post is about [tag:deep-learning].

Comment: OK, I made it a synonym of r-l.  If there are no objections after a period of time, I'll merge them.

Comment: @Sycorax we don't need `[deep-learning]`; it's a shame that even researchers use marketing terms (and, to make it worse, often introduce them).

Comment: @Sycorax do you consider this issue closed by now? (If so, pls mark this as accepted. And maybe edit to reflect what was actually done? We did not replace [deep-rl] as per my comment, we made a synonym.)